# Remove -2 from URL; no duplicate pages, no images, no pages in trash

Tags: permalinks, pages, urls

I've been working or a client and she's getting a -2 in a URL. URL: www.id4africa.com/2017-2.  We originally thought that it was because she had named another page with that slug and then changed it.  We tried deleting the original page but with no luck and tried deactivating all plug-ins and still no luck.  Went to the the Wordpress forum where they have topics on the issue but when clicking on any links regarding this particular issue, they have been removed from their site.  Is there anyone out there that can provide any insight to either fix the problem or find another solution?  Also this client has not had the problem in the past for URLs using Wordpress:

www.id4africa.com/2016
www.id4africa.com/2015

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: it's not possible to have a number as a slug of a page. does http://id4africa.com/2015/ show a wordpress page ? if you want to change this you need to add a filter on `wp_unique_post_slug`